# Magento2 - Sometimes no products showing in categories

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento-community, magento-ce

We have an odd problem where sometimes NO products will show on a category page. This appears to happen randomly across categories.

At other times...all products will be showing just fine.

When none are showing, I can click the Price Filter and then it will show all of the products.

I have cleared/flushed the cache, ran the indexer from the CLI.

We are running V2.1.2

Comment: I do have the same issue, any solution for that?

Comment: has anybody got solution? I have same issue + category doen't show subcategories product sometimes.